# HTML Form input textbox not accepting special characters

Tags: html

There seems to be a problem, where i can't display the complete value in a html form text input box.

$title = "Stacey's Mom";

This is the html code I used to show the value.

Title:

This returns the value in textbox as "Stacey".
Samething happens when "," or "'" or "/" occurs in the text.

How can I show the entire text in the textbox.

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you have an apostrophe, the HTML ends up like this:

```
value = 'Stacey's Mom'
```

So that apostrophe closes the value. What you need to do is use the `htmlspecialchars` function when displaying anything from user input.

I'd also suggest using single quotes for outputting HTML since it can make the code a bit cleaner (you don't need to escape double quotes). Something like this:

```
echo 'Title: <input type="text" name="title' . $counter . '" value="' . htmlspecialchars($title) . '" />';
```